Is it possible to bypass the login for a no longer supported offline app?
There’s an app that I frequently use called ecard manager on android that no longer works.
(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brilliantts.ecard&hl=en_US&gl=US&pli=1)
I believe the company went under. This app was used as a companion to a device called a fuze card. It’s a physical card that you can load your personal credit cards, membership cards, and gift cards onto. Think Apple or android pay but on a physical device. The only online component of the app was the sign in to the app which no longer works. Everything else is completely offline.
https://vulners.com/seebug/SSV:97271]
I’ve tried to contact customer service to no avail. I’ve also tried to reverse engineer it following the guide in the link above, but I’m not tech savvy enough to do it unfortunately. I live in a rural area and a lot of the places near me don’t accept tap pay and I really enjoyed the utility of the fuze card.
My end goal is to be able to add my new credit cards to the fuze card. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
Bluetooth Reverse Engineering, I tried and failed miserably
